# Multiple subdomains to log into phpMyAdmin with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to have 2 separate subdomains from 2 different websites have access to logging into the same phpMyAdmin.

I'm not sure how to set up the `phpmyadmin.conf` file so that Nginx knows how to forward both subdomains to the phpMyAdmin login page.

Here's what my Nginx `server{}` block in  `/etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` looks like.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name pma.example.com;
root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

access_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin_error.log;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
 }

location ~ ^/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
deny all;
 }

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
 }
}
```

So, I'm wondering how I can have both the `pma.example.com` subdomain and the `pma.example.net` redirect to the main phpMyAdmin log in page.

Answer (score 0):

That's not *HTTP redirection*, but the Nginx can serve the same web application from multiple host names or paths. The [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) has

> Syntax:   `server_name name ...;`

in your case:

`server_name pma.example.com pma.example.net;`

...but why on earth would you offer access to phpMyAdmin on an unencrypted connection?! Therefore, I would suggest using a common path, instead. This way you don't have to worry about every domain having an additional certificate or SAN for the subdomain. It is also easy to configure as a global alias.

You could follow, e.g., a [tutorial from Cloudbooklet](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nginx/) which suggest adding a snippet in `/etc/nginx/snippets/phpmyadmin.conf`:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /usr/share/;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /usr/share/;
    }
}
```

Modify it to match your environment: PHP FPM version etc. After that you can simply add `include /etc/nginx/snippets/phpmyadmin.conf;` to every `server {}` block.

Comment: No, never said it was a HTTP redirection. I was referring to the NGINX to redirect to the proper location for the subdomain. To answer your question, I wouldn't ever use port 80. This was just an example NGINX server block prior to getting it's TLS certificate to handle both SSL or TLS encrypted data transfers on port 443 to log in.

As far as the server block goes, I've already tried to no avail:

server_name pma.website1.com pma.website2.com;

This doesn't seem to work when trying to access the two separate websites to log in to phpmyadmin.

Comment: So, just to clarify,  for each website, I'd like to have it to where I can log in from a subdomain for each website.
For example, website1.com will have it's own subdomain to log in to phpmyadmin via pma.website1.com. Then, I'll have another website that has it's own database with website2.com and have it to where I can log in to phpmyadmin from it's subdomain at pma.website2.com.